# Bootstrap 4.2.1 - Navbar recolhido não enche toda a largura da tela

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Basicamente, meu problema é que quando eu tenho minha `navbar` recolhida, os itens da lista não preenchem toda a largura da tela. Eu tentei muitas coisas, mas não consigo encontrar a solução.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código

```js
 /*
  **********************************************************
  * OPAQUE NAVBAR SCRIPT
  **********************************************************
  */

  // Toggle tranparent navbar when the user scrolls the page

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 50)  /*height in pixels when the navbar becomes non opaque*/ 
    {
        $('.opaque-navbar').addClass('opaque');
    } else {
        $('.opaque-navbar').removeClass('opaque');
    }
});
```

```css
.jumbotron {
  color: white;
  background-image: url("https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/img (40).jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 90vh;
}

/* .jumbotron .container h1{
  margin-top: 100px;
} */ 


 

/***********************************************************************
*  OPAQUE NAVBAR SECTION
***********************************************************************/

.opaque-navbar {
    background-color: transparent;
    /* Transparent = rgba(0,0,0,0) / Translucent = (0,0,0,0.5) */
    height: 60px;
    padding: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-bottom: 0px;
    transition: background-color .5s ease 0s, padding 0.5s, height 0.5s;
}

li a{
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255)!important;
  /* background-color: transparent!important; */
  transition: color .1s ease 0s;
}

li a:hover{
  color: rgb(192, 192, 192)!important;
}

.active > a {
  color: white!important;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.096)!important;  
} 

.opaque-navbar.opaque {
    background-color: rgb(48, 48, 48);
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-bottom: 0px;
    transition: background-color .5s ease 0s, padding 0.5s, height 0.5s;
}

ul .dropdown-menu {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

ul .dropdown-menu > a {
  color: black!important;
}

.opaque-navbar.opaque .dropdown-menu{
  margin-top: 4px;
  transition: margin-top 0.5s;
}



.opaque-navbar .dropdown-menu{
  margin-top: 9px;
  transition: margin-top 0.5s;
}


.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle,
.navbar-inverse .nav .open>a,
.navbar-inverse .nav .open>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .nav .open>a:focus {
   background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.096);
   color:white!important;
}
 


@media (max-width: 767px) {

  body{
    background:rgb(255, 255, 255);
  }

  .opaque-navbar {
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 50px!important;
    padding: 0px;
    transition: background-color .5s ease 0s;
  }

  .opaque-navbar.opaque {
    background-color: rgb(48, 48, 48);
    height: 50px!important;
    transition: background-color .5s ease 0s;
  }
  .opaque-navbar .container .navbar-collapse{
    background-color: rgb(48, 48, 48);
    margin-top:0px!important;
    text-align: left!important;
    width:100vw!important;
  }  
  .opaque-navbar.opaque .container .navbar-collapse{
    background-color: rgb(48, 48, 48);
    text-align: left!important;
    width:100vw!important;
  }  
 
  .opaque-navbar .container .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .dropdown div.dropdown-menu{
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-color: rgb(48, 48, 48);
  }
  .opaque-navbar .container .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .dropdown div.dropdown-menu .dropdown-item{
    color: white!important;
  }
  .opaque-navbar .container .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav{
    float: none!important;

  }

  .dropdown-menu > a {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255)!important;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Videojogos</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="img/logo.png" type="image/x-icon">
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style1.css">

    </head>

    <body>

        <!--
        ********************************************************************
        * Responsive Transparent Navbar
        ********************************************************************
        -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-dark navbar-expand-md fixed-top opaque-navbar">
            <div class="container">

                <a href="index.html" class="navbar-left" style="width: 250px; height: 50px;"><img src="img/logoText_white.png" style="width: 250px; height: 50px;" onmouseover="this.src='img/logoText.png'" onmouseout="this.src='img/logoText_white.png'"href="#"></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navMain">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navMain">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a> </li>
                        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a> </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown" style="list-style-type: none;">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Visão Geral (?)
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">O que são?</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Estilos</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Plataformas</a>
                            </div>
                        </li> 

                        <li class="nav-item dropdown" style="list-style-type: none;">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navDropdown1" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Esports
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" >
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">O que são?</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">História</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Organizações</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Torneios</a>
                            </div>
                        </li> 
                        
                    </ul>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- ************************** END OF NAV ************************** -->
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
            <div class="container">
                <h1 class="display-4">Transparent Background Example</h1>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="container" style="min-height:1000px">
            <div class="row" >
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h2>Page Content</h2>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                            <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                            <div class="card-body">
                              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        a
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" style="color:black"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        b
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      c  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

https://codepen.io/MiguelTF/project/editor/XoLPno

Comment: @LipESprY haha nem tinha percebido!

Comment: O problema é o .container que cria max-width automático menor que a largura da tela.

Comment: Seu principal problema mesmo é que vc colocou um div com a classe `.container` dentro da Navbar isso não é correto de acordo com a documentação! https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/ aproveite que está começando e de uma revisada na estrutura do HTML e de como está montando o CSS, tente seguir sempre a documentação oficial, vai evitar esse tipo de problema, E lembre que o Bootstrao já tem estilos CSS para vários nomes de classe como a `.container`, então se for usar nomes genéricos assim opte por `.container-site-x` por exemplo, isso vai evitar conflitos de nome de classe no css